# Tabhost Problem?

Tags: android

I have created a tabhost project and in one of my tab i have a listview and i want to display next activity in the same tab on clicking on a listitem? Please help

Answer (score 0):

i do that in this way:

on the list activity, when user pick a item from the list i send a broadcast intent to the tab activity with the bean id (info id)

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(MyTabActivity.SWITCH_TAB_MAP);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("idBean", bean.getId());
broadcastIntent.putExtras(bundle);
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

when tab activity receives the message, dispatch it to a handler, because onReceive method ran on another thread

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
        msg.what = VIEW_ITEM_ON_MAP;
        msg.obj = bundle;
        handler.dispatchMessage(msg);
    }
```

finally the handler switch the current tab an call a method in the other activity-

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case VIEW_ITEM_ON_MAP:{
                Bundle bundle = (Bundle) msg.obj;
                int idBean = bundle.getInt("idBean");
                ((MyMapActivity)getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(MAPA)).viewItemFromList(idBean);
                getTabHost().setCurrentTabByTag(MAPA);
                break;
            }
    };
};};
```

ps: because TabActivity is an ActivityGroup i use ((MyMapActivity)getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(MAPA)) to get the activity with the "MAPA" id

hope this help you